# I am trying to create a model that generates a list of 256 unique combinations of four characters {a, b, c, d}

Tags: r, for-loop

My problem is with constructing a for-loop that will generate and then collect the 256 combinations. This is my code that I made so far.

```
n <- 10000
letters <- sample(c(1,2,3,4),n, replace = TRUE)
letters
uniquelist <- numeric(n)
mylist <- vector(mode = "list", length = (n-3))
mylist[1] <- 0

for(i in 1:(n-3))
{
  mylist[[i]] <- c(letters[i], letters[i+1], letters[i+2], letters[i+3])
  (n-3) - sum(duplicated(mylist))
  unique(mylist)
  
  for(j in 256:(n-3))
  {
    if (length(unique(mylist[1:j])) == 256)
    {
      break
    }
  }

  uniquelist[i] <- mylist[256]
}
```

Comment: There is no question here. what exactly do you mean by unique combinations? We cannot tell what you want unless you elaborate on what you want. Use `n = 10` and include an expected output

Comment: Are you absolutely **required** (ex. by a teacher) to use a `for`-loop?  If not, this could be done very easily using `expand.grid()`...

Answer (score 4):

This will create a dataframe of 4 columns and 256 rows with all combinations

```
x <- expand.grid(rep(list(c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')), 4))
do.call(paste0, x)
```